# Discrepancy in Stats for StackOverflow's Top Users by Week, Month, Quarter, or Year

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, reputation-leagues

There is a discrepancy in members stats (position/ranking) shown for the StackOverflow's [Top Users](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) by Week, Month, Quarter, or Year on the [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) web page. The listing *incorrectly* displays the user named "Anand S Kumar" as a "Top User" for the *month* and *quarter* period. Whereas, in reality, Anand S Kumar currently sits at the *3rd* position (*see screenshots at the bottom of this post*) as for the *monthly* and *quarterly* ranking goes. He is *only* a top user for the *week* and that part is correctly shown.

Here is the screenshot(showing the concerned area) of https://stackexchange.com/leagues page:

[image]

In the above screenshot, notice the two red checkmarks (*denoting incorrect*) above the user Anand S Kumar's profile picture. You can click on his(*and other users too*) profile picture to validate the current standing for the given period especially for the *month* and *quarter*. And, just out of curiosity (*and to confirm too*), I checked the other users profiles shown for "Super User", "Ask Ubuntu" and "Server Fault" sites and they are perfectly fine. I wonder why the same logic (assuming that the same *program* is used to generate the entire "Top Users" page) is not working for the "Stack Overflow" site. Is this a bug? Something is wrong here. Any idea?

Screenshot of Anand S Kumar's Weekly Position: (*Top*)
[image]

Screenshot of Anand S Kumar's Monthly Position: (*3rd Spot*)
[image]

Screenshot of Anand S Kumar's Quarterly Position: (*3rd Spot*)
[image]

**UPDATE #1**: 7/6/2015 9:40AM CST

The [Top User stats page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) has been updated this morning and I see the following two changes:

1. The user "Anand S Kumar" weekly position is now replaced with another user named "Xan" and I verified it is correct. BUT, "Anand S Kumar" is still listed *incorrectly* for the *month* and *quarter* period.
2. BUT, now there is a new problem popped up. I noticed that the user "DavidPostill" under the "Super User" site has been replaced by username "[Suriya](https://superuser.com/users/435728/suriya)" (hover over his profile picture to get the name) and upon clicking on Suriya's profile picture the listing shows "[user1937198](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser)" is the Top User for the week. How could that be? Here are the two snapshots for your reference

User Suriya is *wrongly* listed as a Top User:
[image]

Whereas, the user "user1937198" is shown as a Top User for the [weekly rank](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser) but I don't see user "Suriya" anywhere on [this weekly list](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser) at all... Another BIG mystery to solve as in my original question the user "Anand S Kumar" was at least seen somewhere (3rd spot) for the given period:
[image]

**UPDATE #2**: 7/6/2015 11:21AM CST

Another thing I noticed, if you check [SuperUser.com Weekly Ranking](https://superuser.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week) then you will notice that user "DavidPostill" still holds the top spot whereas user "Suriya" currently sitting at 9th and the user "user1937198" at the 8th position. So, why is the Stack Exchange Leagues top user list does not match to actual SuperUser.com top user listing? Here is the screenshot for the reference:

[image]

Comment: I'm very happy to see that my stats are correct for [su] ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill not really... You have been toppled by another mysterious user in the *Weekly* standing. Please see my UPDATE section in the question.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue.  Those rankings aren't going to be updated in real time.

Comment: @Servy I completely agree that rankings are not updated in real-time BUT then when they do get updated say for e.g. Daily, then why are they displaying incorrect results

Comment: @HackerKarma I don't know how long this data is cached for, but if this is just a manifestation of caching then it's *not* displaying incorrect results, it's just displaying *outdated* results.

Comment: @HackerKarma They were correct at the time you posted (yesterday - which due to caching was **last week**). They are correct today as it is a **new week** (week starts on Sunday). Due to caching it is only displaying yesterdays rep changes. I got 70 and the other user was the only user to get 200. I'm sure tomorrow it will show me again ;)

Comment: @servy - see my comment above for at least a partial explanation of what HackerKarma is seeing.

Comment: @HackerKarma Your comments about the [su] rankings are caused by a change of week between the two user displays.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok, but then I still don't understand... So where exactly is the CACHING problem? Is it on the results shown on main page i.e. http://stackexchange.com/leagues or at the the http://stackexchange.com/leagues/3/week/superuser

Comment: @HackerKarma The caching problem is that it is not real time. If it was it would show me as #1 right now I think as I have already gained 245 today. ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill also the user "Suriya" who is a Top User on main page for  Super User site is not seen anywhere in the weekly listing... why?

Comment: @DavidPostill main Top User Leagues page is: http://stackexchange.com/leagues I got Suriya by hovering over his profile picture under Super User site

Comment: @DavidPostill also noticed, if i go to http://superuser.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week then you still hold the top weekly spot whereas I see Suriya at 9th AND the mystery user "user1937198" at the 8th

Comment: @HackerKarma I don't know -  Suriya got 110 yesterday so should show up in weekly figures.

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't know either... But, I am sure Stack Exchange developers knows it... I hope to see an answer from them. Added UPDATE #2